# Conditionally add param to URL-Tag in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

Assuming that I want to add a parameter to an url-tag in Struts 2 based on a condition expressed with an if-tag.

What doesn't work ist the following because the param is added to the container which in this case is the if-tag.

```
<s:url id="url" value="path/to/something">
  <s:if test="%{#expression}">
    <s:param name="param" value="value" />
  </s:if>
</s:url>
```

Is there an alternative to the code below which works quite well even if param is unset?

```
<s:if test="%{#expression}">
  <s:set name="param" value="value"/>
</s:if>
<s:else>
  <s:set name="param" value=""/>
</s:else>

<s:url id="url" value="path/to/something">
  <s:param name="param" value="%{#param}" />
</s:url>
```

The snippet will be included several times. That's why `param` is set explicitly to empty (which is converted to null) if the expression evaluates to false.

Comment: Good question. You can use ternary operator inside `value` attribute. BTW `id` of `<s:url>` is deprecated use `var` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't parametrize `if` tag, instead you can wrap the `url` tag around `if/else` tags

```
<s:if test="%{#expression}">
  <s:url var="url" value="path/to/something">
    <s:param name="param" value="value" />
  </s:url>
</s:if>
<s:else>
 <s:url var="url" value="path/to/something">
  <s:set name="param" value=""/>
 </s:url>
</s:else>
```

Comment: Well, imagine having lots of other parameters whch should be added individually based on their own conditions. This would result in code duplication with room for errors.

Comment: It's a different problem.